# Javascript function not defined but it is included

Tags: javascript

What could've happened if I get the error msg `ReferenceError: dragInit is not defined` when I actually include the js file where dragInit is defined?

How can I resolve the error? Why is the function not known when it is included?

The inclusion looks like:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://schema.medinet.dev//common/schema6.js?edb560209503a4f78bda807bc3217559"></script>`

And then later in the page an inlined call generates the error message:

`<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">dragInit();</script>`

The actual function in `schema6.js` look like:

```
function dragInit() {
    document.onmousemove = update;  //  update(event) implied on NS, update(null) implied on IE
    update();
}
```

Comment: Check the network tab, is the script loaded correctly?

Comment: Also, is `dragInit` defined as a toplevel function or is it inside some other definition?

Comment: Double slashes in URLs usually don’t cause problems - but it’s wrong nevertheless, so go and fix that.

Comment: Not the solution to your problem, but you don't need to add `language="JavaScript"` to your script tag. This attribute is deprecated for too long now.

Comment: Also you don't need to define the `type`, as all browsers default this attribute to `text/javascript`

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I checked the network tab and the script appears to be loaded.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca It is toplevel. And if I enter `dragInit` in the console then it is found, which is very strange.

Comment: @NiklasRosencrantz when you add `dragInit` in the console, is this after the page is loaded, or at the point in page lifecycle where `dragInit` is being called?

Comment: @MarkCooper After the page is loaded. I might need to make a bug investigation and look at the page lifecycle if dragInit is being called before it has been loaded, but I don't understand why that could be the case.

Comment: Are we completely out of ideas? I have made no progress for several days.

Comment: @NiklasRosencrantz are you using jquerys document.onready() by any chance?

Comment: @MarkCooper No, not that I know. But I will check.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to check:

- Check the script has loaded correctly - look for 404's in the network tab
- Check the order in which scripts are loaded - is `dragInit()` available when it is called?

You can use most browser tools to debug the JavaScript as it is running. Take a look at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/Debugging_JavaScript) for details on how to do this.

Comment: This is not an answer, these are suggestons better fitting a comment.